# A max/min problem

Tags: calculus

I am supposed to find maximum and minimum for $$y = \frac{2}{(x-2)^2}-x$$ and I'm having trouble with it. Can anybody help me?

Comment: what are you allowed to use? what is the range for x? what did you try?

Comment: Do you know to use a derivative to find min/max?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a simple question standing for so long..neither OP nor anyone appears to be concerned..

Answer (score 1):

There is neither a maximum nor a minimum for this. Since it diverges to $+\infty$ as $x$ tends toward $-\infty$ and diverges to $-\infty$ as $x$ tends toward $+\infty$.

Comment: Probably the OP means local maxima or minima.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer given by galois is not the answer the instructor wants because the problem is looking for local minima or maxima.  (Yes, the problem is slightly poorly worded.)

The derivative of $y$ is 
$$
-\frac{4}{(x-2)^3} -1
$$ and setting that to zero gives just one real solution 
$$
x = 2 - \sqrt[3]{4}
$$
And it is easy to see that this is a minimum, since the second derivative is positive.

There is no maximum.

And by the way, even without the funny business at $x=2$, a function can easily have both a minimum and a maximum and yet diverge in this same way.  Consider 
$$,
y = x - \frac{x^3}{3}$$ which as a minimum at $-1$ and a maximum at $+1$.

Comment: The problem is not looking for local minima or local maxima. Perhaps the original problem was, but this problem certainly is not... Well, its a good lesson to be precise in your wording for OP.